# How can I use backreference of the following groups?

Tags: javascript, regex

I can use backreference for the following group like this:

```
(A)(B)(C)\1\2\3
```

But, how can I use the backreference for the following types of group:

```
((A)(B(C)))
```

Comment: This will help you: http://regex101.com/r/vG3jL6/1

Comment: please share some inputs as well.

Comment: @anubhava I'm unclear a little bit. what would be the match result of this: ((A)(B(C)))\1\2\3\4

Comment: `ABCABCABCC` will match your regex `((A)(B(C)))\1\2\3\4`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Javascript backreferences for regular expressions count up from the outside-in:

e.g. for `((A)(B(C)))`:

- `((A)(B(C)))` is `\1`
- `(A)` is `\2`
- `(B(C))` is `\3`
- `(C)` is `\4`

Comment: Yes and that is true in any other regex flavor also.